# How to prevent unintended blocks from being added?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, pymupdf

The top of my input file's third page:
[image]

The top of my output file's first page:
[image]

The first few blocks of my output file's first page:
[image]

Why was the source file's page number added as well? I thought it was because it's in the header, but the footer wasn't added alongside it to confirm such a suspicion. `ez_save()` doesn't work. `scrub()` doesn't work.

The clipping window for `show_pdf_page()` was set to precisely the topmost point of the question number. No extra padding space was taken so I'm confused as to why it detected the page number.

Similarly, I also have a section where I *only* grab the central footer (the QP number) from the source pdf's middle page (for this particular file, it happened to be page 11 where question 4 resides). When I add it, I can see the QP number is added as a content (instead of a footer), but when I print the blocks, I also see the entirety of question 4 (the parts of page 11) listed, so... What's up with that?

Here's the code to set a collection of `Rect` objects to be used to clip from the source file.

```py
def fetchQuestionList(file, Q1Page, edge, Q1Top, Q1Bot):
    listOfQuestions = []
    questionBoxes = {}
    currentQuestion = 0
    for page in file.pages(Q1Page):
        # As soon as you enter a new page and an existing question was already being scanned in the previous page,
        # immediately add a new rectangle as a potential continuation of the question from the previous page
        if currentQuestion != 0:
            questionBoxes[currentQuestion]['rects'].append(fitz.Rect(0,Q1Top,page.mediabox.x1,0))
            questionBoxes[currentQuestion]['pages'].append(page.number)
        pageWords = page.get_text("words")
        for wordIndex, word in enumerate(pageWords):
            # If a new question number is found
            if word[0] < edge and word[4].isdigit() and word[5]>1 and word[-1] == 0:
                if currentQuestion != 0:
                    # Update the currently scanning question's rectangle's bottom to the top of the new question
                    questionBoxes[currentQuestion]['rects'][-1] += fitz.Rect(0,0,0,word[1])
                    # If the old question's rectangle is not even as tall as a single line, discard it from the list
                    if questionBoxes[currentQuestion]['rects'][-1].height < Q1Bot - Q1Top:
                        questionBoxes[currentQuestion]['rects'].pop()
                        questionBoxes[currentQuestion]['pages'].pop()
                # Add the new question and also update the currentQuestion to the newly found question
                listOfQuestions.append(list(word)+[page.number])
                currentQuestion = word[4]
                questionBoxes[currentQuestion] = {'rects': [fitz.Rect(0,word[1],page.mediabox.x1,0)], 'pages': [page.number]}
            # If the last word of the page has been reached, set the current question's rectangle's bottom to the bottom of this last word
            elif wordIndex == len(pageWords) - 1:
                questionBoxes[currentQuestion]['rects'][-1] += fitz.Rect(0,0,0,word[3])

    return listOfQuestions, questionBoxes
```

The `edge` parameter is the right coordinate (`x1`) of the question number '1' (the pymupdf 'word', not 'block'). The conditions `word[5]>1 and word[-1]==0` are just fail-safes. The first two conditions generally suffice.

And here's the code to actually create the output pdf.

```py
def generateQuestionwisePDF(file, QPNUM, questionList, questionBoxes, padding):
    newPDF = fitz.open()
    for _, rectPageDict in questionBoxes.items():
        # Generate pages
        pageHeight = padding
        for rectIndex, rectangle in enumerate(rectPageDict['rects']):
            pageHeight += rectangle.height
            pageHeight += padding/2
        pageHeight += padding/2
        blankPage = newPDF.new_page(width=file[0].rect.width, height=pageHeight)

        # Paste content
        pasteBox = fitz.Rect(0,0,file[0].rect.width,padding)
        for rectIndex, rectangle in enumerate(rectPageDict['rects']):
            pasteBox = fitz.Rect(0, pasteBox.y1, pasteBox.x1, pasteBox.y1 + rectangle.height)
            blankPage.show_pdf_page(pasteBox, file, rectPageDict['pages'][rectIndex], clip=rectangle)
            pasteBox = fitz.Rect(0, pasteBox.y1, pasteBox.x1, pasteBox.y1 + padding/2)
    return newPDF
```

I've omitted the use of `QPNUM` parameter so only one problem can be focused on at a time. But in short, the QPNUM is also a 'word' containing the coordinates of the qp number from page 11 (with the page number itself appended).

UPDATE:

[This is the source pdf](https://pastpapers.papacambridge.com/viewer/caie/as-and-a-level-physics-9702-2023-may-june-9702-s23-ms-34-pdf-9702-s23-ms-35-pdf-9702-s23-ms-41-pdf-9702-s23-ms-42-pdf-9702-s23-ms-43-pdf-9702-s23-ms-51-pdf-9702-s23-ms-52-pdf-9702-s23-ms-53-pdf-9702-s23-qp-11-pdf-9702-s23-qp-12-pdf-9702-s23-qp-13-pdf-9702-s23-qp-21-pdf)

This is starting to drive me nuts. I tried using the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74963837/crop-pdf-content-with-python-not-just-the-cropbox) but got a `source object number out of range` error. This error occurs during the second execution of `show_pdf_page()` because introducing a print page's blocks statement right before it gave me the contents of both the source pdf's pages 3 & 4.

As an alternative, I tried to test if `set_cropbox()` can delete outside content [despite the documentation saying it only changes visible part](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.set_cropbox), and it turns out, it does!.......... until it doesn't.

Code edit summary:

- Added a dummy blank pdf in the beginning of `generateQuestionwisePDF()`: `anotherPDF = fitz.open()`
- Inside the `# Paste content` for loop, added the following code

```py
            cropPage = file[rectPageDict['pages'][rectIndex]]
            cropPage.set_cropbox(rectangle)
            if rectPageDict['pages'][rectIndex]== 2: 
                print("---------USING PAGE------------")
                for block in cropPage.get_text('blocks'): print(block)
```

- Just before the `return` statement, added the following code

```py
    print("---------USING DOC[0] BEFORE SAVE------------")
    for block in anotherPDF[0].get_text('blocks'): print(block)
            
    anotherPDF.save("another.pdf")
    print("---------USING DOC[0] AFTER SAVE------------")
    for block in anotherPDF[0].get_text('blocks'): print(block)
```

And the result?
[image]

And to really nail it home, I tried to select text in the output file, and...
[image]

Comment: Going to need to share your code (not an image) and the pdf please.

Comment: Why did you tag this with `python` and then not share any python code?

Comment: my bad just a moment

Comment: i was under the impression this was a pymupdf handling issue and a small adjustment of function use could've handled it instead of requiring tracing through a large block of code. anyways, here u go.

Comment: i added comments for clarity for the first code

Comment: added an update after further attempts